# Need a udev rule to create a symbolic link to a usb memory stick when it is plugged in

Tags: usb, mount, udev

My usb drive has id 580000911.  It gets mounted as `/media/ubuntu/580000911`.   I would like a `udev` rule to create a symbolic link to it like this `/media/ubuntu/USBDRIVE`.   I created this udev rule file:

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="58??????", \
RUN+="rm /media/ubuntu/USBDRIVE", \
RUN+="ln -s /media/ubuntu/$env{ID_FS_LABEL} /media/ubuntu/USBDRIVE"
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="58??????", \
RUN+="rm /media/ubuntu/USBDRIVE"
```

It does not work.   I don't know if I am on the right track or not. Any suggestions?

Comment: I thought `SYMLINK` is meant for that?

Comment: I will see what I can learn about symlink.   It seems like what I tried should work.

Comment: Have you tried using `udevtest` to debug the rule?

Comment: I see `\\`, rules are oneliners so that should not be there

Comment: I use `udevadm monitor` to help write my scripts. Simply start it, then plug in and un-plug your USB stick. Copy and paste terminal output into your script.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix wonderful never knew this

Comment: @George Glad to share the knowledge. I need to write a script warning when cell phone is not plugged in and being charged. Maybe I should write a tutorial/answer to this question at the same time.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix sure would love that...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.   I am using udevadm test to learn what will work.   When/if  I find a solution I will post it here.

Comment: @Bob I'm glad it all worked out. Don't forget to accept it in 24 hours or so. In the mean time I upvoted your answer.  Welcome to ***Ask Ubuntu*** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="58??????", RUN+="/bin/rm /media/ubuntu/USB", RUN+="/bin/ln -s /media/ubuntu/$env{ID_FS_LABEL} /media/ubuntu/USB"
ACTION=="remove", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL}=="58??????", RUN+="/bin/rm /media/ubuntu/USB"
```

Apparently we have to use the complete pathname for any commands we want to run.

Comment: Would you please accept this answer as this what worked for you, so other users can find this solution easily. See [about]